# Propositional Logic and Conditional Statement translation.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

On the basis of abbreviation A: Sarah is clever; B: Tom goes to school; C: Tom's sister will go home; how would you translate the following formula into natural English?

$A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$.

I had problems with translating this formula into meaningful English sentence. Should I use only if or unless to convert formula back into English words? What are optimal suggestions?

Comment: How are we totally ordering suggestions in order to determine which one is optimal?

Comment: Are you allowed to use alternative ways of saying "If ... then"? If so, then maybe: If Sarah is clever, then Tom going to school is sufficient for Tom's sister to go home.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro   Yes, alternative translations are much preffered

Comment: You *could* note that $p\to(q\to r)$ is equivalent to $(p\wedge q)\to r$ and give an obvious translation of the latter; but English does not lend itself easily to conditional sub-clauses inside conditional clauses.

Comment: You could say, "Suppose Sarah is clever."  Then, if Tom goes to school, Tom's sister will go home."

Comment: @amWhy Yeah, it seems your sentence sounds much better!

Comment: Though that is more like $A\models B\implies C$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can you prove that relation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then we could say "Provided Sarah is clever, then if Tom goes to school it follows that Tom's sister will go home."

Comment: What relation? The equivalence? $p\to(q\to r)$ is false if and only if $p$ is true and $q\to r$ is false, so it is false if and only if $p$ and $q$ are true, and $r$ is false. $(p\wedge q)\to r$ is false if and only if $p\wedge q$ is true and $r$ is false, hence it is false if and only if $p$ and $q$ are true and $r$ is false. Hence, the two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: @amWhy "Provided" also seems good choice, can we also state "If Sarah is clever, then Tom goes to school only if Tom's sister will go home"?

Comment: Following @ArturoMagidin's suggestion, it is equivalent to say "If Sarah is clever and Tom goes to school, then Tom's sister will go home."

Comment: Yes, @AnarRzayev !

Comment: Realize that there are many ways to say, in natural language, what is not ambiguous in logic.

Comment: I'd suggest you answer this question yourself, @AnarRzayev !  I think you've found a few good options.  Take some time answering, so your answer can be helpful to others trying to translate propositional statements of the form $P\to (Q\to R) \equiv (P\land Q) \to R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Community Wiki post to reveal the truth tables, which demonstrate that $$P\to (Q\to R)\, \text{ is equivalent to } \, (P\land Q) \to R$$ as Arturo pointed out in the comments above.

Truth-Table for $P\to (Q\to R)$:

[image]

Truth-Table for $(P\land Q) \to R$:

[image]

---

As you can see, each is true in all truth value assignments, save for when $P, Q$ are true, but $R$ is false.